# Am I writing these numerals correctly as words?

Tags: writing, time

Please let me know if there is something wrong in the following examples:

> - am 12. April 1961 – am zwölften April,   neunzehnhunderteinsundsechzig Jahre
> - mit 35 Jahren – mit   fünfunddreißig Jahren
> - 3600 Meter – dreitausendsechshundert Meter

Comment: If you don't provide the English version, how do we know if it's a correct translation or not? Besides, instead of asking for the whole sentence, what parts are harder for you?

Comment: As the answers say, you're mostly correct... in the spelling.  *But* you generally don't spell out numbers as large as 3600 or 1961.  36 can be spelled out, but that's already borderline.

Answer (score 13):

I guess you want to write down the digits into letters.

Regarding the date: This is mostly correct – but "Jahre" must not be mentioned explicitly. It’s simply:

> "am zwölften April neunzehnhunderteinundsechzig".

By the way, the "eins" (1) in the spelled-out version is shortened to "ein" (without the s). For example:

> 71 : "einundsiebzig"

not "einsundsiebzig". This applies to two-digit-numbers in general.

The rest are all correct.

Comment: For the date you *must* not use the word "Jahre" unless you say "am zwölften April im Jahr[e] XY".